# Ruby On Rails - Default object_type depending on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a Post model that can be either an Article or Video.

Here is my Post model:

`Post(id :integer, user_id :integer, post_type :string, created_at :datetime, updated_at :datetime)`

Thus, I have:

1. `class Article < Post`
2. `class Video < Post`

Is there a specific syntax that I can add to both Aricle and Video models, so that I can do the following things:

1. `Article.create`, automatically set `post_type` to `"article"`
2. `Article.all`, shows only posts where `post_type == "article"`

Samething goes for Video model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Single Table Inheritance (STI).

You could either change the column `post_type` to `type` for being close to the `rails` defaults.

Or, you could define your custom inheritance_column as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = 'post_type'
end

class Article < Post
end

class Video < Post
end
```

Then `rails` take care of storing either the `Article` or `Video` info in the `type` or `post_type` column.

Refer to [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In the Article model add this for automatic post_type assigning:

```
def initialize
  super
  self.post_type = :article
end
```

Then also add this default scope for automatic filtering:

```
default_scope -> { where(post_type: :article) }
```

Add the same to the Video model, except change :article to :video.